# Polymorphic event notification model in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a polymorphic notification model. When user gets a notification he can get on the page of the notifiable to check  out what happened exactly. For instance `invited you to join product` or `commented on a post`. On the top of this I also have a polymorphic comment model. So user can get a notification not only for `commented on a post` but also for `commented on a product customer`or `commented on a product`, which of course just makes the whole situation more complex.

So the flow is the  following:

If the user clicks on the notification, the link redirects to the custom `checking_decreasing` action to check the notification and decrease the notification number if necessary, and then it redirects to the desired page with anchor.

As you see my `notification_redirection_path` action looks terrible and I'm not even sure if it should be in application controller. Any ideas how I could refactor this code?

notifications index page (there is also a json version for dropdown notifications)

```
<%= link_to checking_decreasing_user_notifications_path(
      current_user,
      notifiable_type: notification.notifiable_type, 
      notifiable_id: notification.notifiable_id, 
      notification_action: notification.action
     ) do %>
```

notifications_controller

```
def checking_decreasing
  current_user.decreasing_comment_notification_number(
    params[:notifiable_type], 
    params[:notifiable_id]
  )
  redirect_to notification_redirection_path(
    params[:notifiable_type], 
    params[:notifiable_id], 
    params[:notification_action]
  )
end
```

application controller

```
def notification_redirection_path(notifiable_type, notifiable_id, action)
  if action == "commented"
    if notifiable_type == "ProductCustomer"
      product_customer = ProductCustomer.find(notifiable_id)
      product_id = product_customer.product_id
    elsif notifiable_type == "ProductLead"
      product_lead = ProductLead.find(notifiable_id)
      product_id = product_lead.product_id
    end
    route = case notifiable_type
            when "Post"
              posts_path(anchor: "post_#{notifiable_id}")#{}"/posts#post_#{notifiable_id}"
            when "Product"
              product_path(notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel")#/products/#{notifiable_id}#comment-panel"
            when "ProductLead"
              product_product_lead_path(product_id, notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel")#{}"/products/#{product_id}/#{notifiable_type}/#{notifiable_id}#comment-panel"
            when "ProductCustomer"
              product_product_customer_path(product_id, notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel") #/products/#{product_id}/#{notifiable_type}/#{notifiable_id}#comment-panel"
            end
  elsif action == "invited"
    product_path(notifiable_id, anchor: "product-invitation-well")
  elsif action == "accepted"
    product_product_users_path(notifiable_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really basic refactor of `notification_redirection_path`:

```
def notification_redirection_path(notifiable_type:, notifiable_id:, notification_action:, **)
  case notification_action
  when "commented"
    case notifiable_type
    when "Post"
      posts_path(anchor: "post_#{notifiable_id}")
    when "Product"
      product_path(notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel")
    when "ProductLead"
      product_lead = ProductLead.find(notifiable_id)
      product_product_lead_path(product_lead.product_id, notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel")
    when "ProductCustomer"
      product_customer = ProductCustomer.find(notifiable_id)
      product_product_customer_path(product_customer.product_id, notifiable_id, anchor: "comment-panel")
    end
  when "invited"
    product_path(notifiable_id, anchor: "product-invitation-well")
  when "accepted"
    product_product_users_path(notifiable_id)
  end
end
```

A few things to notice:

1. I changed the method arguments to keyword arguments. This way instead of doing this:

   ```
   redirect_to notification_redirection_path(
     params[:notifiable_type], 
     params[:notifiable_id], 
     params[:notification_action]
   )
   ```

   ...we can do this:

   ```
   redirect_to notification_redirection_path(params)
   ```
2. I turned the outer `if` expression into a `case` expression. I also changed the indentation so the `when`s line up with their `case`. Usually I prefer the other style (like you wrote it) but I find with nested `case`s this is a bit easier to read.
3. I removed your initial `if notifier_type == ...` expression and moved that logic into the `when "ProductLead"` and `when "ProductCustomer"` blocks below. No need to have those in two separate places.

This is still pretty messy, though. A quick win for readability, maintainability, and testability would be to split it into separate methods:

```
def notification_redirection_path(notifiable_type:, notifiable_id:, notification_action: nil, **)
  case notifiable_type
  when "commented"
    commented_notification_redirection_path(notifiable_type, notifiable_id)
  when "invited"
    product_path(notifiable_id, anchor: "product-invitation-well")
  when "accepted"
    product_product_users_path(notifiable_id)
  end
end

private
def commented_notification_redirection_path(type, id)
  case type
  when "Post"
    posts_path(anchor: "post_#{id}")
  when "Product"
    product_path(id, anchor: "comment-panel")
  when "ProductLead"
    product_lead = ProductLead.find(id)
    product_product_lead_path(product_lead.product_id, id, anchor: "comment-panel")
  when "ProductCustomer"
    product_customer = ProductCustomer.find(id)
    product_product_customer_path(product_customer.product_id, id, anchor: "comment-panel")
  end
end
```

You could employ [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path) to take this to its extreme conclusion, which might look something like this:

```
ACTION_ANCHORS = {
  "commented" => "comment-panel",
  "invited" => "product-invitation-well"
}

def notification_redirection_path(notifiable_type:, notifiable_id:, notification_action:, **)
  if notification_action == "commented" && notifiable_type == "Product"
    return posts_path(anchor: "post_#{notifiable_id}")
  end

  notifiable = notifiable_type.constantize.find(notifiable_id)

  path =
    if notification_action == "commented" &&
        (ProductLead === notifiable || ProductCustomer === notifiable)
      [ notifiable.product, notifiable ]
    elsif notification_action == "accepted"
      [ notifiable, :product_user ]
    else
      [ notifiable ]
    end

  polymorphic_path(path,
    anchor: ACTION_ANCHORS[notification_action])
end
```

...but it's probably not worth it, since you lose a lot in readability and maintainability.